# Error for writing algorithms on the swift

Tags: swift, xcode, algorithm

I've been working on nutrition app for ios lately. I'm trying to write this algorithm

> weight (lb) / [height (in)]2 x 703

in xcode with swift, but I'm beginner to use swift. I wrote this code

`let calculate = ((textforweight.text) / ((textforheight.text)*(textforheight.text))*703)`

and it gives me error like "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" that. Can you help me for this. It might be so easy but I just don't know how to do it

Comment: are you trying to do math with strings? If so, convert them to numbers first, then do math with the numbers.

Comment: you need to unwrap your textfield `text` property (optional String) and coerce it to Int `if let weight = Int(textforweight.text!) { ...`. The same apply to the other textFields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UITextField** `.text` property return a String value.So you need to convert this value to Int first

```
let weight = Int(textforweight.text!) ?? .zero
let height = Int(textforheight.text!) ?? .zero
```

Now You can Calculate you result,

```
let result = weight / height * height * 703
```

[UITextField .text Property Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text)

Comment: `textforweight.text ?? "0"` is pointless. The default value will never be assigned. UITextField text property default value is an empty string therefore it will never return `nil`. `Int(textforweight.text!)` Btw Int string initializer returns an optional integer. Your code wouldn't compile as it is. `Int(textforweight.text!) ?? .zero`

Comment: @selimerhan check the last edit. Btw you can't divide a number by zero. It will result in `nan` and you probably would need to use a `Double` instead of an integer to calculate your result.

Comment: I checked the last edit, it doesn't give any errors but the algorithm doesn't give the correct answer, Idk why. I use the double as you said but still doesn't work